# React RouterProvider with Context API not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have react router set up in my App component as

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Products from "./components/Products";
import ProductDetails from "./components/ProductDetails";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { ProductContext } from "./contexts/ProductContext";
import { LoadingBarContext } from "./contexts/LoadingBarContext";
import LoadingBar from "react-top-loading-bar";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Products />,
    },
    {
        path: "products/:asin",
        element: <ProductDetails />,
    },
]);

const App = () => {
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");
    return (
        <>
            <LoadingBar color="#f11946" progress={progress} onLoaderFinished={() => setProgress(0)} />
            <ProductContext.Provider value={{ products, setProducts, keyword, setKeyword }}>
                <LoadingBarContext.Provider value={{ progress, setProgress }}>
                    <Navbar/>
                    <RouterProvider router={router} />
                </LoadingBarContext.Provider>
            </ProductContext.Provider>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

How can I navigate to a route let's say '/' in my navbar component?
Basically I want to render the **products** component when user clicks on the Home link. I tried using **Link** in Navbar components but it is showing error.

```
import React from "react";

function Navbar() {
    return (
        <>
            <nav className="w-full py-1 bg-white border-b border-blue-400">
                <div className="container mx-auto flex items-center justify-between">
                    <h1 className="text-xl font-medium text-blue-600">Amazon Scraper</h1>
                    <ul className="flex items-center justify-between text-base text-blue-600">
                        <li>
                            <a className="inline-block  hover:text-blue-500 font-medium py-2 px-4 " href="/">
                                Home
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a className="inline-block hover:text-blue-500 font-medium py-2 px-4 " href="/" >
                                About
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only overt issue I see is that you are rendering raw anchor tags to navigate, which when used will reload the page and reset any component/app state (*unless it's being persisted to and initialized from localStorage*).

The error when trying to use the RRD `Link` component in the `Navbar` component is that they are being used ***outside*** any routing context, i.e. what `RouterProvider` provides.

You can fix this by creating a layout route component that renders the `Navbar` component and an `Outlet` for nested routes to render their `element` content into.

Example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Products from "./components/Products";
import ProductDetails from "./components/ProductDetails";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";
import { ProductContext } from "./contexts/ProductContext";
import { LoadingBarContext } from "./contexts/LoadingBarContext";
import LoadingBar from "react-top-loading-bar";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Products />,
      },
      {
        path: "products/:asin",
        element: <ProductDetails />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

const App = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <LoadingBar
        color="#f11946"
        progress={progress}
        onLoaderFinished={() => setProgress(0)}
      />
      <ProductContext.Provider value={{ products, setProducts, keyword, setKeyword }}>
        <LoadingBarContext.Provider
          value={{ progress, setProgress }}
        >
          <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </LoadingBarContext.Provider>
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className="w-full py-1 bg-white border-b border-blue-400">
      <div className="container mx-auto flex items-center justify-between">
        <h1 className="text-xl font-medium text-blue-600">Amazon Scraper</h1>
        <ul className="flex items-center justify-between text-base text-blue-600">
          <li>
            <Link
              className="inline-block hover:text-blue-500 font-medium py-2 px-4"
              to="/"
            >
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link
              className="inline-block hover:text-blue-500 font-medium py-2 px-4"
              to="/"
            >
              About
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```